# Mosquitto on Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I'm trying to install my Mosquitto broker on an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2023.

I have tried using
sudo yum -y install mosquitto

But it says that they are unable to find a match. I have read that I need to install the EPEL packages, but this are not compatible with Amazon Linux 2023. How can I install Mosquitto then?

Thank you and best regards